# Angular : DevExtreme DataGrid State Storing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devexpress, devextreme

I'm using the DevExtreme **DataGrid widget** under my Angular app.

here is the view of my datGrid:

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="employees"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true"
    [allowColumnResizing]="true"
    [columnAutoWidth]="true">
    <dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-chooser>
    <dxo-column-fixing [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-fixing>
    <dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="custom" savingTimeout="2000" [customSave]="tableStateSave" [customLoad]="tableStateLoad"></dxo-state-storing>
    <dxi-column
        caption="Employee"
        [width]="230"
        [fixed]="true"
        [calculateCellValue]="calculateCellValue"
    ></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="BirthDate" dataType="date"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="HireDate" dataType="date"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Position" alignment="right"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Address" [width]="230"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="City"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Zipcode" [visible]="false"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="HomePhone"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="MobilePhone"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Skype"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Email"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

As you cas see in this line :

```
<dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="custom" savingTimeout="2000" [customSave]="tableStateSave" [customLoad]="tableStateLoad"></dxo-state-storing>
```

I'm using custom methods to load **(tableStateLoad)** and save **(tableStateSave)** my DataGrid state (columns positions and sizes).

State saving is done after every changing action automatically within a timeout of 2 seconds.

But i wanna **replace this automated saving action** by a manual one with a simple button .

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: `grid.instance.state()` returns state that you can save

Comment: @yurzui don't understand , how may i use it

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/e6w27E8sjbx1elVHWbqv?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui that partially helped me,  but s.th still missing ; if we eliminate the timeout of saving , if saves it automatically ( savingTimeout=" " ) , how may i elimnate that automatc saving , and keep just the button click to do it

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution without  `dxo-state-storing` in your grid.

In your `dx-grid` simply insert:

`[stateStoring]="stateSorting"`

And

For the `dxo-column-chooser` you can add the select mode:

```
                <dxo-column-chooser
                            [enabled]="true"
                            mode="select">
                </dxo-column-chooser>
```

As in the following HTML:

```
<dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="employees"
    [stateStoring]="stateStoring"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true"
    [allowColumnResizing]="true"
    [columnAutoWidth]="true">
    <dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true" mode="select"></dxo-column-chooser>
    <dxo-column-fixing [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-fixing>
    <dxi-column
        caption="Employee"
        [width]="230"
        [fixed]="true"
        [calculateCellValue]="calculateCellValue"
    ></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="BirthDate" dataType="date"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="HireDate" dataType="date"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Position" alignment="right"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Address" [width]="230"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="City"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Zipcode" [visible]="false"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="HomePhone"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="MobilePhone"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Skype"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Email"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

In your typescript file, you can simply import the following:

```
import DevExpress from "devextreme";
import StateStoring = DevExpress.common.grids.StateStoring;
```

And add the state storing functionality:

```
    public stateStoring: StateStoring = {
        type: 'localStorage',
        enabled: true,
        storageKey: 'stackOverflowGridStorage'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dxo-state-storing` directive without specifying a custom save method:

```
<dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="custom" savingTimeout="2000"  [customLoad]="tableStateLoad"></dxo-state-storing>
```

or just set the `customSave` property to an empty function. That way the state gets automatically loaded, but is not saved in any way. Then you implement a button that has a click handler with your custom saving logic, accessing the current grid's state with `grid.instance.state()`.